# PYTHON3 - Union and Intersection of DataFrame's Series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have stored in  two dataframes some series. Lets say A and B.

Each dataframe has 8 series and I wish to perform the following operation to them.

A[i] UNION B[i] UNION (A[i] INTERSECT B[i]). The way that I am trying to do it is the following:

```
for item in the_list:

    A_SET = pd.Index(A[item])
    B_SET = pd.Index(B[item])

    first_union  = A_SET.union(B_SET)
    second_union = first_union.union(A_SET.intersect(B_SET))
```

This happens successfully for the first item but then I get the following error message:

> pandas.core.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Is this because some of the series have NaN values? If so, is it possible to make the union accept also NaN values and remove them from the result? Also, the series do not have the same length

### An Example of the error

```
A_SET = pd.Index([1,2,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,5])
B_SET = pd.Index([3,2,1,5,6,np.nan])


A_SET.union(B_SET)
```

### What solved the issue

```
A_SET = pd.Index([1,2,3,4,np.nan,np.nan,5]).dropna(how='all')
B_SET = pd.Index([3,2,1,5,6,np.nan]).dropna(how='all')
A_SET.union(B_set)
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample ?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the example and included the `nan`, 
since

```
np.nan==np.nan 
False
```

Which mean when we do the union , it will not remove the nan from the second index, example as below :

```
A_SET = pd.Index([1,2,3,4,3,np.nan])
... B_SET = pd.Index([1,2,3,90,np.nan])
first_union = A_SET.union(B_SET)
... 
first_union.union(A_SET.intersection(B_SET))
Float64Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 90.0, nan, nan, nan], dtype='float64')
```

If you would like to treat your `NaN` equal to each other do `fillna` with string type `'NaN'`

Like

```
A_SET.astype(object).fillna('NaN').union(B_SET.astype(object).fillna('NaN'))
Index([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 90.0, 'NaN'], dtype='object') 
# notice the np.nan become the string NaN and the type become object
```

Comment: I solved the issue by using pd.Index.dropna() on the two sets inside the loop.